# UIScrollView is stopping too soon

Tags: xamarin.ios, uiscrollview

I'm using a scrollview to make a image gallery for my app and I have it mostly working. it'll allow me to scroll through the images one by one but the very last image always get cut off and I'm not sure why.

this is the bulk of the operation:

```cs
var idx = 0;

foreach (var mediaItem in _mediaItems)
{
    var xPosition = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width * idx;
    var imageView = new UIImageView();

    imageView.SetImage(new NSUrl(mediaItem), UIImage.FromBundle("image_placeholder"));
    imageView.Frame = new CGRect(xPosition, 0, svGallery.Frame.Width + 50, svGallery.Frame.Height);
    imageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;

    svGallery.ContentSize = new CGSize
    {
        Width = svGallery.Frame.Width * (idx + 1)
    };
    svGallery.AddSubview(imageView);

    idx++;
}
```

minus that flaw, this works perfectly and as I expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From shared code , the `Width` of `ContenSize` is:

```
Width = svGallery.Frame.Width * (idx + 1)
```

However, each `Width`(`svGallery.Frame.Width + 50`) of `ImageView` is greater than `vGallery.Frame.Width`:

```
imageView.Frame = new CGRect(xPosition, 0, svGallery.Frame.Width + 50, svGallery.Frame.Height);
```

Therefore, the actually `Width` of `ContenSize` can not contains all the `ImageView`'s Content. And if the number of ImageView is larger, the last picture will be cut off more.

You can modif the `Width` of `ContentSize` as follow to check whether it works:

```
svGallery.ContentSize = new CGSize
{
    Width = (svGallery.Frame.Width + 50) * (idx + 1)
};
```